# How get real positions of element in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

[image]

I want to get real X and Y position of my styled elements in javascript ( or jquery short code).

```
var offset = obj.offset();
  ox=offset['left']; 
  oy=offset['top']; 

  px=parseInt(obj.css('padding-left')); // padding left
  py=parseInt(obj.css('padding-top')); // padding top
  bx=parseInt(obj.css('border-width') ); // stroke value
  ox=ox+px+bx;
  oy=oy+py+bx;
```

But this codes sometimes not work..

when scrool top or scroll left change im not get real position :(

please help me..

Comment: Are you getting unreal position now ?

Comment: (OT) try always to use *dot* notation: `offset.left` , and don't forget that `parseInt` likes his *radix* parameter.

Answer (score 20):

You don't have to use offsets. Use the modern [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) function:

```js
function getPosition( element ) {
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: rect.left,
        y: rect.top
    };
}
```

You could then use the above function like this:

```js
var element = document.getElementById( 'myElement' );
var pos = getPosition( el );

// Alert position in X axis
alert( pos.x );

// Alert position in Y axis
alert( pos.y );
```

Works in all browsers

**EDIT:** If you want the position of the element with respect to page scroll, just add `document.body.scrollTop` to Y position and `document.body.scrollLeft` to X position.

Comment: +1 This is the only way to account for margin.  offsetLeft is limited.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the offset from the element relative to the document. You have to keep in mind that styles like padding, margin and border can greatly affect the result of the offset. You might want to calculate those on or off the offset.

Finally you need to check if you are using `box-sizing`, which pushing padding and borders to the inside (with the most common version `box-sizing: border-box;`);

```
document.getElementById('cloud').offsetLeft; //offsetTop
```

Just debug with the other styles (adding/subtracting) until you get the real offset. I mostly test if the offset is correct by making a screenshot (or using the OS X selective-screenshot function) to see if the offset is correctly calculated (counting pixels) with the other styles.

Here's a little example:

**CSS**

```
#cloud {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px dotted #CCC;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="cloud">
        <div id="centerBox"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
'use strict';

console.log(document.getElementById('cloud').offsetLeft);
console.log(document.getElementById('cloud').offsetTop);
```

***Ouput***

```
main.js: 1 >>> 372
main.js: 2 >>> 20
```

Funny thing here, you can easily test if the `offsetLeft` works because of the `margin: 20px auto;`. If you resize the window it will also have a different `offsetLeft`.

Comment: var offset = obj.offset();
      ox=offset['left']; = document.getElementById('Mypicture').offsetLeft;

Two codes are get equal value.. but not get padding,border values :(

Comment: Did you read everything in my answer? I already explained that you have to take into account those factors. And by the way; they do the get the "real" values, but not the ones that you want. I already noted in my answer that you have to see which spatial factors change the basic offset, like padding and borders. Also don't use negative margins/paddings unless it's really necessary. It's bad practice. And remember that if you do `padding: 20px;` the height of the element will become 40px (2x20px) higher.

Comment: and by `box-content` you mean `box-sizing` right?
http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html

Comment: offset won't account for margin.  `getBoundingClientRect().left` (for example) will, and you don't have to traverse the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This function gives you the exact position of an element without padding or margin or border:

```
function getElementRec(element) {
    let rec = { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 }; 
    
    let computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);
    rec.width = element.clientWidth;
    rec.width -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingLeft);
    rec.width -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingRight);
    rec.height = element.clientHeight;
    rec.height -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingTop);
    rec.height -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingBottom);
    
    let boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    rec.x = boundingRect.left;
    rec.x += parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingLeft);
    rec.x += parseFloat(computedStyle.borderLeft);
    rec.y = boundingRect.top;
    rec.y += parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingTop);
    rec.y += parseFloat(computedStyle.borderTop);
    
    return rec; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     var offset = obj.offset();
      ox=offset['left']; = document.getElementById('Mypicture').offsetLeft;
      oy=offset['top'];  = document.getElementById('Mypicture').offsetTop;
    px=parseInt(obj.css('padding-left')); // padding left
    py=parseInt(obj.css('padding-top')); // padding top
    bx=parseInt(obj.css('border-width') ); // stroke value
    ox=ox+px+bx;
    oy=oy+py+bx;

//Two codes get equal value;  But Not Real clientX ClientY positions..
```

// My html:

```
    <div id="container">
    <img id="Mypicture" src="myimage.jpg"  alt="The source image for paint"/>
    </div>

//My css :

  #Mypicture{
  margin:100px;
  padding:20px;
  border: 20px solid #cacaca;
  }

  #container {
  display:block;
  background:#ffaaff;
  width: 550px;
  padding:50px;
  margin-left:300px;
   }
```

// I want to get realx and realY value of Mypicture,on Document.
   // All codes work  Realx ( ox )  return true value But RealY (oy)  nearly 10px false;